# Opening editAction in all cells in the same time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I want to use editActionForRowAt but for all rows in tableView. 
Something like this: [edit actions (random image from web)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmKPh.png)
but for all cells in the same time. This action should be triggered by a button located on the navigation bar.
In al tutorials I've read, there is always only for one cell...

Comment: At the same time question needs editing!

Comment: In my application it looks like this: 1. no editing 2. start edit (this is action in second button from left) 3. edit action show up when I click red button on the left[1] Can some one show me how to display actions in all rows in the same time?

[1]: i.stack.imgur.com/55IH1.png 
[2]: i.stack.imgur.com/PenWk.png 
[3]: i.stack.imgur.com/VjWxf.png 

Can some one show me how to display actions in all rows in the same time?